# event.preventDefault() does not work in $locationChangeStart case

Tags: angularjs

I am using the following code:

```
$rootScope.dirtyValueForm=true;
    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
         if ($rootScope.dirtyValueForm) {
               event.preventDefault();
         }
    });
```

When I am trying to change location path, `event.preventDefault()` does not prevent it! Any idea/solution?

Comment: It will stop. There may be another reason for that. Please provide more code

Answer (score 0):

Also try adding: [`event.stopImmediatePropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/)

Comment: Nothing! Very weird

Comment: @ILIAS did you tried adding breakpoint on that line? Did it stopped?

Comment: Yes, it stopped